# Error NU2010: Platform version is not present for one or more targets

Tags: c#, maui-blazor

> :Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error NU1012  Platform version is not present for one or more target frameworks

Even though they have specified a platform: net6.0-ios, net6.0-maccatalyst

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Run maui-check, and do everything it says.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you add more context to the question? What are you trying to do? And also, it isn't even clear what the question is exactly

Comment: You can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1012). It tells how to deal with NU1012.